# Doubt in the following program regarding the value of GPIO_PORTF_DATA_R

Tags: embedded

The following code is related to tiva c series tm4c123gh6pm board

```
    #include <stdint.h>
    #include "inc/tm4c123gh6pm.h"

    int main(void)
    {
        unsigned int value;

        SYSCTL_RCGCGPIO_R |= 0x20; /* enable clock to GPIOF */
        GPIO_PORTF_DIR_R = 0x0E; /* set PORTF 1, 2 & 3 pins as output (LED) pins */
        GPIO_PORTF_DEN_R = 0x1E; /* set PORTF pins 1, 2, 3, and 4 as digital pins */
        GPIO_PORTF_PUR_R = 0x10; /* enable pull up for pin 4 */

        while (1)
        {
            value = GPIO_PORTF_DATA_R; /* read data from PORTF */
            value = ~value; /* switch is low active; LED is high active */
            value = value >> 1; /* shift it right to display on the red LED */
            GPIO_PORTF_DATA_R = value; /* put it on the red LED */
        }
    }
```

According to my understanding, when switch is pressed, the pin4 corresponding to PORTF is activated. Since the switch is active low, the corresponding value becomes 0 in **GPIO_PORTF_DATA_R** making the value of this register as **0b xxx0 xxxx**. I'm unable to understand how this value is becoming 0x02 when all bits are inverted and shifted to right by one bit. I tried to dump this code in the board and it's working perfectly(i.e., when switch is pressed, red led is glowing).

Comment: Step through the code in the debugger while watching the value of `value`.  (You may need to disable optimizations to see the results of each line individually.)  Double check the schematic to ensure the red LED is on the pin you expect.

Comment: We have read this **0b xxx0 xxxx** form value GPIO_PORTF_DATA_R register.

Next, we invert this value **~0b xxx0 xxxx** so we get this 
**0b xxx1 xxxx**

Now we shifted to the right by one **0b xxxx 1xxx**
And we send it back to GPIO_PORTF_DATA_R register. This works because we have a switch on pin PF4 and the LED on pin PF3.

Answer (score 3):

### Debugging the code from the question

Based upon the information in the question, I assume the code is being run in a [EK-TM4C123GXL](https://www.ti.com/tool/EK-TM4C123GXL). The [Tiva™ C Series TM4C123G LaunchPad Evaluation Board User's Guide](https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/spmu296/spmu296.pdf) contains the following table which shows the connections for the LEDs and switches on the board:
[image]

I added the code from the question into a CCS 12 project for a TM4C123GH6PM so could debug by single stepping. Before stepping into the `while` loop the LEDs on the board are all off. The [TM4C123GH6PM datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/tm4c123gh6pm) description of the *GPIO Data (GPIODATA)* register shows that the register is initialised to zero on reset.

The result of stepping through the `while` loop after starting the program while **not** pressing any button is:

| Value read from `GPIO_PORTF_DATA_R` | Value written to `GPIO_PORTF_DATA_R` | Comment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0x00000014 | 0x7FFFFFF7 | RGB LED changes from Off to Blue+Red On (Magenta) |
| 0x00000016 | 0x7FFFFFF4 | RGB LED changes from Blue+Red On to Blue On |
| 0x00000014 | 0x7FFFFFF5 | RGB LED remains at Blue On |
| 0x00000014 | 0x7FFFFFF5 | The *shift register* on `GPIO_PORTF_DATA_R` is now stable |

The `SW1` button was pressed and continued stepping:

| Value read from `GPIO_PORTF_DATA_R` | Value written to `GPIO_PORTF_DATA_R` | Comment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0x00000004 | 0x7FFFFFFD | RGB LED changes from Blue On to Green+Blue On (Cyan) |
| 0x0000000C | 0x7FFFFFF9 | RGB LED changes from Green+Blue On to Green On |
| 0x00000008 | 0x7FFFFFFB | RGB LED changes from Green On to Green+Red On (Yellow) |
| 0x0000000A | 0x7FFFFFFA | RGB LED remains at Green+Red On |
| 0x0000000A | 0x7FFFFFFA | The *shift register* on `GPIO_PORTF_DATA_R` is now stable |

So, effectively the code is creating a *shift register* on some bits of the `GPIO_PORTF_DATA_R` register, where the output bits for the LEDs can be read back on the next iteration around the while loop.

### Consider changing from Direct Register Modification (DRM) only programming to using TivaWare

The [[FAQ] FAQs for TM4C Arm Cortex-M4F Microcontrollers](https://e2e.ti.com/support/microcontrollers/arm-based-microcontrollers-group/arm-based-microcontrollers/f/arm-based-microcontrollers-forum/695568/faq-faqs-for-tm4c-arm-cortex-m4f-microcontrollers) on the Texas Instruments forum contains the following:

> **4) Avoid use of Direct Register Modification (DRM) only programming, and instead use TivaWare**.
>
> One of the primary purposes of TivaWare has been to remove the need for individual users to learn the ins and outs of DRM programming. For this reason, we will not be able to offer support for any questions that only pertain to DRM programming.

Where the code from the question is using *DRM programming*. If the program was re-written to use TivaWare functions it could be clearer. E.g. the `GPIOPinWrite` function takes the `ui8Pins` argument which is a bit-mask of which GPIO port output bit(s) to update. By changing the code to use TivaWare `GPIOPinWrite` could be used to only update the `PF1` state for the RGB LED (Red) on the board.

If required, could modify this answer to add an example of how the DRM code in the question could be converted to TivaWare.